# In tasker, trigger when airplane mode is turned off

Tags: tasker, airplane-mode

Using Tasker, I'd like to send an SMS when Airplane Mode goes from 'On' to 'Off'.

I can see a state called 'Airplane Mode' however I can't work out how to detect the transition from 'Airplane Mode On' to 'Airplane Mode off'.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways to do this:

1. Checking the "Invert" tag on the Airplane Mode state, causing it to become active when Airplane Mode is off.
2. Using the Mobile Network state to detect when the device is connected to a mobile network (check all network types if you're not sure which to use).